# How to fetch the count of consumer_id in the Query string parameter of HTML request in Protractor

Tags: javascript, npm, protractor

[image: img]

I need to get the count of consumer_id, if the count is equal to 1 proceed with the further testing else logout from that count.

How to achieve this?

```
describe('Test Payment Page', function () {
var paymentPage = new PaymentPage();
var loginPage = new LoginPage();
testData.forEach(function (data) {
    it('should have a title', function () {

        loginPage.getPage();
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
        loginPage.enterUsername(data.username);
        loginPage.enterPassword(data.loginpwd);
        loginPage.clickLoginButton();

        paymentPage.clickPaymentButton();
    });

    it('Should validate if the accounts are linked', function () {

        request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://172.28.136.26:5005//documents/',
            Querystring: {
                consumer_id: 'consumer_id'
            },    
        });
    })
});
```

})

Comment: Can we see your code please?

Comment: Im actually struck in the middle, after clicking on payment button im looking to fetch the consumer_id count,